# models.Model_memory Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I want to know, since I've never seen this type of model before `models.Model_memory`

How can it be translated into new Odoo v10 API?

Should it be `models.TransientModel`?

**EDIT**

This is the method where `models.Model_memory` is is used:

```
class FiscalBookWizard(models.Model_memory):

"""
Sales book wizard implemented using the osv_memory wizard system
"""
    _name = "fiscal.book.wizard"
```

Comment: Where do you see this class defined? Please share some code

Comment: Done, seems like it's osv_memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since v9 wizards must be implemented with `models.TransientModel`.

In v9 osv_memory works because of backward compat, but is deprecated.

See [official docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/backend.html#wizards).